# Why is my NSAttributed String losing its attributes when the view reappears?

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, font-awesome, nsattributedstring

I am using UIAppearanceProxy in my app, like so:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel appearance];
label.font = myAppFont;
label.textColor = myAppTextColor;
```

Sometimes, though, I want to override the default font to use glyphs from [Awesome Font](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/). I do that like this:

```
    NSString *basePos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", (int)self.user.positives, kUpArrow];
NSMutableAttributedString *posString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:basePos];
[posString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:18]} range:NSMakeRange([posString length] - 1, 1)];
[self.positivesLabel setAttributedText:posString];
```

This works great when the view is built and appears, but if I navigate to another page (I am using UIPageViewController) and back, my attributes are gone.

I've tried re-setting-up the attributes in:

- viewWillAppear:
- viewDidAppear:
- viewWillLayoutSubviews
- viewDidLayoutSubviews

...to no avail. When is this string getting reset to the default? And how can I override that?

Comment: How do you reset the attributes?

Comment: At the moment just repeating the code that sets it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing was happening in to me.

The reason that this was happening was because I had set the `font` property on the appearance proxy of `UILabel`, and for whatever reason that overtook the attributes of the attributed string when the view re-appeared.

I fixed this by setting the `font` property on the `UILabel` to `nil` before setting the `attributedText`. Note that setting the `font` to any font also fixed this issue; it does not necessarily need to be set to `nil`.